# Selecting distinct row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure how to search for this and hence I started a new question.

I have a table in the following structure

```
----------------------------------------
| TALKS            |    PERSON
----------------------------------------
| Networks         |  John Doe   
| Steganography    |  Alex
| Assembly         |  Mark
| Networks         |  Mark
| Steganography    |  John Doe
| Networks         |  Mark
----------------------------------------
```

How do I perform a query so that I get

```
----------------------------------------
| TALKS            |    PERSON
----------------------------------------
| Networks         |  John Doe   
| Steganography    |
| Assembly         |  Mark
| Networks         |  
| Steganography    |  Alex
----------------------------------------
```

Note that 'Mark' has two talks on 'Networks', but it needs to return only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT talks, person FROM table

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve what you are trying

```
(
  select talks,name 
  from table1
  group by name  
  order by talks
)
UNION ALL
(
  select distinct talks as talks, 
  case 
    when name is not null then ''
  end
  name
  from table1
)
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a23/12)**

Answer (score 0):

You have two things going on in your implied specification. One is display the distinct talks, and the second is formatting the result set to avoid repeating the name of a single person in consecutive rows.

This query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc2d3/4/0) does both.

```
select talks,
       if (@prev = person,'',@prev:=person) person
  from (
         select distinct talks, person
           from talk
          order by person, talks
       ) AS a,
  (select @prev := '') AS init
```

An alternative query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc2d3/9/0) which avoids the @variable monkey business is

```
select group_concat(distinct talks order by talks) AS talks,
       person 
  from talk
 group by person
```